# how can I view the value in memory location 0x0?

Tags: assembly, memory-management, gdb, kernel, cpu

everyone,I really want to view the value in any location of my memory. 
i want to see what's the value in the the memory location 0x0 at one moment.
and im curious about what's inside all my cpu's registers too.

i used DEBUG in 32-bit windows,but DEBUG doesn't exist in 64-bit windows any more. i tried to use linux GDB, but i failed when i type in 'x/10xb 0x0',that means i wanna check the very first 10 bytes from memory location 0x0. the GDB returns "Cannot access memory at address 0x0"

introduce me more backgroud knowledges are better.as you see ,this question from a begginer who wanna know more about computer system.

Comment: Every process has its own address space.  Your question doesn't make very much sense.

Comment: Virtual memory address 0 is not typically mapped so that null pointer accesses can be detected. Physical memory address 0 is not directly accessible to user processes. You can of course view registers in any debugger, and the contents of any valid memory for your process.

Comment: hi,dear the first added comment. i know ,i point to x86 i.e. IA32 architecture.maybe it's nothing for you,but important for me.

Comment: hi,dear ,Jester.yes i point to the physical memory i.e.the linear address.i tried windows DEGUG in the CLI(that black back ground window),it works fine... it seems i turned on a GOD mode :)

Comment: IA32  is an i386 instruction set, operation system do matter too and you're not on DOS if you talk about gdb. 32bit widows also were varying by memory model, if you use something from 90s, you had to specify that.

Comment: dear,Swift,based on 32 bit linux how can i view the value in physical adress 0x0, i guess i should not be empty.

Comment: 0x0 never allowed to read by posix standard. A you have misconception of linear address: https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2005/readings/i386/c05.htm

Comment: @Swift Note that the POSIX standard doesn't forbid this either.

Comment: On Linux, you can look at the memory by opening `/dev/mem` and `/dev/kmem`.

Comment: thank you ,dear Swift.i didnt care too much about paging.but i think you understand the meaning of my question: how can i view the value in any physical memory location that what i want???? by windows DEBUG i can.but by linux GDB, i cant now. the intel at least always has a real mode.not all in protected mode right?as we learned in the operating system courses.

Comment: @fuz, really thank you.i think you know more. First,from the cpu's point of view,it really doesnt care too much about segmentation or paging,if the segmentation cant satisfy your requirements , i give you paging,it's not very difficult to think from the cpu's point of view.Second,we we talk about the core of OS(linux) there is a step that the core jump from cpu real mode to protected mode,right?

Comment: real (or flat) mode reached limit of allowed address memory when we had 1 mb ram.

Comment: @fuz that's work around i mentioned. that is virtual device, reading from which invokes kernel subroutine to read from kernel memory space. but even that might be not a bottom bottom of physucal memory (virtualization, heh?), but may be. what i meant is performing read operation on level of cpu instructions

Comment: @Swift now the 32-bit os is running,that means i can't view what's inside a physical memory address that i point out ? ? for example , 0x 12 34 56 78?

Comment: @Swift by windows DEBUG I can even view what's inside my bios rom. had you ever tried while you were at school?

Comment: a)security b)avoiding fragmentation c) virtually using more space that hardware available

Comment: When in 32-bit protected mode even with paging enabled the OS can still access all the physical memory in the system when running at ring 0. It can keep track of the virtual and linear address to physical address mappings. Your application is likely running in ring 3 using virtual addresses so doesn't see physical addresses. That doesn't mean the OS  itself can't access.An OS can give access to such memory through a system call if it so chooses.That is an OS detail. fuz already mentioned above on Linux you can read /dev/mem device to access physical addresses if you are running with root privs

Comment: @Swift really thank you, i understand your idea. but i bought the computer and i use GNU softwares,so i have the rights to access the physical memory.if the microsoft or apple etc.dont wanna persons do so.it's another thing.

Comment: @MichaelPetch i have tried "sudo vi /dev/mem" ,nothing shows.....what should i do now ?and why does nothing show?

Comment: Assuming you are booted into a real version of Linux you can do `dd if=/dev/mem bs=4096 count=1 | hexdump` That will give a hex dump of the first 4k of physical memory. This will not work with Bash on Ubuntu for Windows (WSL). If you see a lot of `f000` then you are looking at low physical memory as `f000` is the segment where most of the BIOS interrupt vectors exist. The first 1024 bytes of memory are the interrupt vector table.

Comment: When I mentioned the interrupt vector table in my last comment I meant the real mode interrupt vector table.

Comment: @MichaelPetch very very thank you! I've seen them .here is the copy:0000000 eef3 f000 eef3 f000 e2c3 f000 eef3 f000
0000010 eef3 f000 ff54 f000 070f f000 06b7 f000
0000020 fea5 f000 e987 f000 eef3 f000 eef3 f000
0000030 eef3 f000 eef3 f000 ef57 f000 0000 efff

Answer (score -3):

0 address is special case of "address to nothing". Modern PCs use page memory model, each process uses own memory space, you cant see actual memory content unless you work from kernel space. Address 0x0 usually isn't mapped, while some areas may be read only or non-executable.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to provide some links to some doc highlighting your point?

Comment: @assettouf i provided keywords "memory model" , mapped memory and others for reference. Such lst you ask for can be obtained by simple search, while would be quite extensive.

Comment: let's take the answer of Mr. @Michael Petch